# I need help on sorting this table

Tags: php, sql

How do i sort this table with SURNAME only like A to Z on a Ascending order. For exaple

> Aaron Hamster
>
> Barnie Indigo
>
> George Jumper
>
> Mein Kampf

```
$sql = "SELECT id, ln, fn, mi, math, english, science FROM g1";
$result = $link->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // IF RECORD COUNT = 0 
//Pag-gawa ng table
echo
"<div align='center'>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th> Surname </th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Middle Initial</th>
<th>Math</th>
<th>English</th>
<th>Science</th>
<th>Final Grade</th>
</tr>
</div>";
while($row =  $result->fetch_array()) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ln'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fn'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mi'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['math'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['english'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['science'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else {
echo "No records have been saved yet.";
}
```

Comment: Use an `order by` clause in your SQL query.

Comment: Like this?

$sql = "SELECT id, ln, fn, mi, math, english, science FROM g1 ORDER BY ln ";

Answer (score 0):

you can use `order by` in your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, ln, fn, mi, math, english, science FROM g1 ORDER BY  ln ASC";
$result = $link->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // IF RECORD COUNT = 0 
//Pag-gawa ng table
echo
"<div align='center'>
<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th> Surname </th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Middle Initial</th>
<th>Math</th>
<th>English</th>
<th>Science</th>
<th>Final Grade</th>
</tr>
</div>";
while($row =  $result->fetch_array()) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ln'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fn'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mi'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['math'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['english'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['science'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
else {
echo "No records have been saved yet.";
}
```